# angular 6 how to fetch data from YTS API

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular6

hello somebody can help me to fetch data from YTS API

service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Movies} from '../models/movies.model';

@Injectable ()

export class MovieRequestService {
  private url = 'https://yts.am/api/v2/list_movies.json?limit=50';
  moviesData: {movies: Movies} = {
    movies: undefined
  };
  constructor(private myHttp: HttpClient ) {
    this.myHttp.get(this.url).subscribe(
      (response: Movies) => { this.moviesData.movies  = response; });
    console.log(this.moviesData);
  }
}
```

second file component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MovieRequestService } from '../../shared/services/movie-request.service';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Movies } from '../../shared/models/movies.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-list',
  templateUrl: './movie-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-list.component.css']
})
export class MovieListComponent implements OnInit {
  localData: {movies: Movies};
  constructor(private movieService: MovieRequestService, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.localData = this.movieService.moviesData;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

one more file i did model of movies

```js
import { Movie } from './movie.model';

export interface Movies {
  data: {
    movies: [Movie];
  };
}
```

and last one model of movie

```js
export interface Movie {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  year: number;
  runTime: number;
  genre: string[];
}
```

maybe i'm write something right ?
i fetch data from api to console but i can't fetch data to page
somebody can help me ?

Comment: Isn't a good practice to store data inside a service like that. You should return the observable and subscribe to it where you are calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service should just provide calls, not the data itself. So lets take another approach.

Service

```
export class MovieRequestService {
  private url = 'https://yts.am/api/v2/list_movies.json?limit=50';
  constructor(private myHttp: HttpClient )  {

  }

  getMovie() {
    return this.myHttp.get(this.url);
  }
}
```

Component

```
export class MovieListComponent implements OnInit {
  localData;
  constructor(private movieService: MovieRequestService, private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let sub = this.movieService.getMovie().subscribe(response => this.localData = response);
  }
}
```

Or maybe you want to pass the callback as a parameter. In this case:

Service

```
export class MovieRequestService {
  private url = 'https://yts.am/api/v2/list_movies.json?limit=50';
  constructor(private myHttp: HttpClient )  {

  }

  getMovie(callback) {
    return this.myHttp.get(this.url).subscribe(callback);
  }
}
```

Component

```
export class MovieListComponent implements OnInit {
  localData;
  constructor(private movieService: MovieRequestService, private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.movieService.getMovie(response => this.localData = response);
  }
}
```

I prefer the first option since you have control of the subscription.

Comment: but now how i get data into page ?

Comment: @ygorazevedo how can I log the response in the component?

Comment: @AnthonyFink use the localData object in your page to bind

Comment: @AnthonyFink like you would do with any other variable in Angular. Assuming that the response returns a single Movie object: `<p>{{movie | json}}</p>`

Comment: @Vivek you mean ngFor ?

Comment: @Vivek you could change the callback to log it and then do the attribution. Like follow: `response => {console.log(response); this.localData = response;};`

Comment: @AnthonyFink if the return is an `Array` yes. `*ngFor` will do the trick for you.

Comment: in console it back me Subscriber
closed: true
destination: SafeSubscriber {closed: true, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: null, syncErrorValue: null, …}
isStopped: true
syncErrorThrowable: true
syncErrorThrown: false
syncErrorValue: null
_parent: null
_parentSubscription: null
_parents: null
_subscriptions: null
__proto__: Subscription

Comment: so how can i get Array of movies ?

Comment: @AnthonyFink check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ki4yvc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: If it's not working is probably a problem wit the API, no the code. The API wasnt working here but I imagined that it was because the proxy was blocking it. I changed to another API and it works fine. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ki4yvc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmovie.service.ts

Comment: yeah i see placeholder api have an array with objects, but there it bit different. check srtucture of yts api. may you got the idea to bring data from this api

Comment: Ok, it returns some abstraction of a Page object. So you would do something like `response => this.localData = response.data.movies` I'll update the stackblitz

Comment: What I can say is. Seems like you are having struggles about Javascript itself, like how handle JSON objects and so. The code was essentially right, you just had to adapt the subscription to the object that comes from the response. But now should be working. I can't test it here because my work's proxy blocks the request but should be fine now.